# Pymongo not modifying all matching documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I'm trying to update around 100k documents using pymongo 3.12. I believe I'm using the pymongo api correctly, but every time I run a bulk write; it only updates roughly half of the documents that it matches with.

```
upserts = [UpdateOne({'_id': event["$set"]["metaData"]["id"]}, {'$set': event["$set"]}, upsert=True)
                   for event in events_update_data]
result = cursor.bulk_write(upserts, ordered=False)
print(result.bulk_api_result)
```

Results in:

```
{'writeErrors': [], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 427, 'nMatched': 116940, 'nModified': 43303, 'nRemoved': 0, 'upserted': removed_by_me}
```

So why is it matching with all the documents I need it to, but only modifying half? I have to run this multiple times for it to update all docs, and the consistency varies greatly. Here is the operation for each document.

```
data = {"$set": {f'inventoryData.{self.parse_time}': event.pop("inventory"), 'metaData': event}}
```

I've also tried different variations of upserting. All reproduce the same result.

```
bulk_operations = cursor.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
    for event in events_update_data:
        bulk_operations.find({'_id':  event["$set"]["metaData"]["id"]}).upsert().update({"$set": event["$set"]})
        result = bulk_operations.execute()
        print(result)
```

and

```
        upserts = []
        for event in events_update_data:
            upserts.append(UpdateOne({'_id': event["$set"]["metaData"]["id"]}, {'$set': event["$set"]}, upsert=True))
            if len(upserts) == 1000:
                try:
                    result = cursor.bulk_write(upserts, ordered=False)
                    upserts = []
                except BulkWriteError as e:
                    print(e.details)
                print(result.bulk_api_result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `nMatched` is higher then your `nModified`, then chances are your "updates" are the same as the original record, hence not modified.

Comment: Is there some syntax I can use to force it to update the data even if it is unchanged from the original doc? Its storing data every hour, but needs to store it regardless if it has changed from the previous hour or not, Thank you

Comment: Not sure why you would want to, but maybe `replace_one` / (bulk) `ReplaceOne` https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=replace_one#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one?